# How to get progress bar running during garbage collection process?

Tags: android, dalvik, android-progressbar

Clicking on one of the tabs is causing delay of a second or two.
Can't confirm that's the calculation delay or the garbage collector delay to free up the memory for a bitmap which is on that tab.

The log is having some dalvik processing to free up memory like -

> 04-02 11:45:58.109: D/dalvikvm(1930): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1638K, 21%
>   free 15516K/19591K, paused 12ms+4ms, total 222ms

Is there a way to run Progress bar during the time the VM is freeing the memory for the bitmaps ?

This way the application user doesn't have to wait on a tab click as sometimes the delay is long enough that the user may think that nothing is happening.

Comment: 222 ms is 1/5th of a second. That can't make a delay of 2 seconds.

Comment: Sorry, the delay varies according to device and data. My mobile is slower than my tablet for this process. The above is for tablet.

Comment: I don't think you have a delay because of the GC.

Comment: The *total* time for the GC was 200ms.  The *pause* time for the GC was in two pieces, one 12ms and one 4ms.  The log shown in the question is not the cause of a second-or-two delay.

Answer (score -1):

Use Asynctask concept in android , place user garbage clean in Doinbackgroud method , for example [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

Comment: First of all you don't have control over GC. If you call System.gc(), that doesn't mean that GC will start. Also GC runs in a separate thread by itself.